# GregorianCalendar in Android (add Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY vs Calendar.HOUR)

Tags: java, android, calendar

To add an hour to current time, can I use this?

```
Calendar mcalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
mcalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1); //I plan to use 24 hours format
```

I see many examples using instead:

```
Calendar mcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mcalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
```

Comment: As an aside you don’t have to use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
Duration duration = Duration.ofHours( 1 ) ;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ).plus( duration ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter
                      .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                      .withLocale( Locale.GERMANY) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> Sonntag, 27. Dezember 2020 um 22:58:52 Nordamerikanische Ostküsten-Normalzeit

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes. Never use `Calendar` or `GregorianCalendar`.

### UTC

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC. Use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
```

Define a span-of-time unattached to the timeline.

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofHours( 1 ) ;
```

Addition.

```
Instant instantHourLater = instant.plus( duration ) ;
```

### Zoned

You may want to see the time-of-day and date of that moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region. Apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId ) ;
```

Or, skip the `Instant` and the `Duration`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ).plusHours( 1 ) ;
```

### Text

You said:

> I plan to use 24 hours format

The classes such as `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` represent a moment, a point on the timeline. They have nothing to do with text. They do not have a “format”. They can parse text representing a moment, and they can produce text representing a moment. But internally they have their own way of representing that moment, without any formatted text.

To produce text in a particular format, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class with [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) and [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html). This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter
                      .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                      .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) 
;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/LUVwHj).

> output: dimanche 27 décembre 2020 à 22 h 51 min 57 s heure normale de l’Est

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar mcalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
```

The `GreogorianCalendar` is a subclass of the abstract class `Calendar`. Therefore what you are doing here is referencing an instance of the GregorianCalendar to the Calendar therefore all the abstract methods in `Calendar` will follow the implementation of `GregorianCalendar`

But since your purpose is to add Hours.

You can go ahead with `Calendar mcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();` as it retrieves an instance to the current with the the current `Locale`.

However, if you want to change your `Locale`, pass in the parameter into the `getInstance()` method and an instance of the specified `Locale` will be generated for you.

Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)

And if you want to use Hours:

Do the following:

Do not use `HOUR` variable as this is only for 12 hour times. Use `Calendar.HOUR_Of_DAY` to deal with 24 hour timings.

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing GregorianCalendar and it works fine in my phone. I'm more interested in GregorianCalendar than in Calendar.

Comment: What do you want to know about `GregorianCalendar`?

Comment: Thanks @Lakindu; I've seen tutorials advising the use of it in java in general; so I just wanted to make sure that Android is fine with GregorianCalendar used in the way I describe above.

Comment: Yes Android is fine with it. But if you are dealing with 24 Hours make sure to use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` as `Calendar.HOUR` handles only 12 hour timings

Comment: FYI, both `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` are *terrible* date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on these legacy classes.